# Column Ignored Creating Unique Index

Tags: sql-server

Given a view

```
CREATE VIEW MyView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT  A, B, Year, t1.FKId, C, D, COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt, SUM(W) As Wgt
FROM [dbo].[T1] t1
INNER JOIN [dbo].T2 t2 ON t1.FKId = t2.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].T3 t3 ON t1.FKId = t3.FKId AND t1.FKId = t3.FKId
GROUP BY A, B, Year, t1.FKId, C, D
```

When I try to make that an indexed view

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_CLU_My
ON MyView (FKId, A, B, Year, C, D)
```

SQL Server complains about a duplicate key, but the error message only considers 5 of the 6 columns specified:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MyView' and the index name 'IX_CLU_My'. The duplicate key value is (934, 1, 6, 2014, 1).

The actual data present in the view corresponding to the first 4 keys is:

```
FKId   A  B  Year  C  D
934    1  6  2014  1  5
934    1  6  2014  1  15
934    1  6  2014  2  5
934    1  6  2014  3  5
```

Considering the first 5 columns, the error message would be correct.  Why is the 6th column not considered for uniqueness?

Comment: You only have 4 rows returned from your view?

Comment: @RickS: No, those are the ones relevant to this conflict.  There are a few 100K rows in the view in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a HAVING clause and no records come back then I will help you troubleshoot this further.

```
SELECT  A, B, Year, t1.FKId, C, D, COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
FROM [dbo].[T1] t1
INNER JOIN [dbo].T2 t2 ON t1.FKId = t2.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].T3 t3 ON t1.FKId = t3.FKId AND t1.FKId = t3.FKId
GROUP BY A, B, Year, t1.FKId, C, D
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I did run that query.  That's how I got the data shown in the question.  It is run against the tables involved, not the view.

Comment: So the query Rick S suggested returned some records?  If so, then you definitely have duplicate records, right?

Comment: I'm not really clear if OP is 100% sure there are no duplicates based on the 6 columns. I know the error message only includes 5 but you never know about Microsoft error messages and what they really mean.

Comment: @RickS: The data shown in the question is all of the rows returned from the view selecting `WHERE FKId=934 AND A=1 AND B=6 AND Year=2014` .  As you can see, there is a potential conflict where `C=1`, but it is not a conflict because `D` has different values for each row.  The error message implies that `D` is not being used as part of the key.

Comment: if you have a problem with duplicates, just run the query where you select all the PK from all the tables involved and the duplicate will be obvious.

Comment: It turns out there was a cut-and-paste error moving the query from SSMS to code where it is automatically run (column missing in index).  I'm accepting this answer because it got me on the right path.